# JS/PHP убрать одинаковые OPTIONS и вывести все значения

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, массивы, html-select

Имеем файл .json в котором список городов и офисов, где в одном городе может быть несколько офисов:

Получаем его и декодируем и сортируем по городу

```
$json = file_get_contents('offices.json');
$addressarray = json_decode($json, true);
uasort($addressarray, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a["city_name"] == $b["city_name"]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a["city_name"] < $b["city_name"]) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

На выходе получаем примерно такой массив:

```
  [123]=>
  array(8) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "564"
    ["streetAddress"]=>
    string(61) "г.Богородицк, ул.Пролетарская"
    ["region_name"]=>
    string(31) "Тульская область"
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(20) "Богородицк"
    ["workhours"]=>
    string(55) "пн-сб с 09:00 до 19:00, вс с 10:00 до 18:00"
  }
  [57]=>
  array(8) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "254"
    ["streetAddress"]=>
    string(59) "г.Брянск, ул.Брянского Фронта,"
    ["region_name"]=>
    string(31) "Брянская область"
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(12) "Брянск"
    ["workhours"]=>
    string(53) "пн-сб с 9:00 до 20:00, вс с 9:00 до 17:00"
  }
  [129]=>
  array(8) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "617"
    ["streetAddress"]=>
    string(48) "г.Брянск, ул.Пересвета"
    ["region_name"]=>
    string(31) "Брянская область"
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(12) "Брянск"
    ["workhours"]=>
    string(81) "пн-пт с 08:00 до 20:00, сб с 08:00 до 19:30, вс с 09:00 до 18:00"
  }
```

Здесь видно, что для одного города может быть несколько офисов.

Создаем выпадающий список с выбором города, тоже отсортировано:

```
<select id="selectItem">
<?
$json = file_get_contents('offices.json');
$addressarray = json_decode($json, true);
uasort($addressarray, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a["city_name"] == $b["city_name"]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a["city_name"] < $b["city_name"]) ? -1 : 1;
});
foreach ($addressarray as $arr) {
        array_multisort($arr);
            echo "<option id='".$arr['city_name']."'>".$arr['city_name']."</option>'>";
        }
?>
</select>
```

Здесь получается задача 1: один и тот же город будет повторяться несколько раз, что неверно.

Далее, вот таким скриптом пытаюсь вывести для конкретного города свои значения:

```
<style>.containerss div {display: none;}</style>
<div class='containerss'>
<?
foreach ($addressarray as $arr) {
        array_multisort($arr);
        echo "
                <div class='".$arr['region_name']."'>
                    <p style='text-decoration: none;color: hsl(345,89%,49%);font-weight:1.0'>Область: ".$arr['region_name']."</p>
                    <!--<p>Город: ".$arr['city_name']." </p>-->
                    <p>Адрес: ".$arr['streetAddress']." </p>
                    <p>Рабочие часы: ".$arr['workhours']."</p>
                    <p>Телефон: ".$arr['phone']." </p>";
                    if ($arr['extendedAddress']) {
                        echo "<p>Доп. инфо: ". $arr['extendedAddress']." </p>";
                    }
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<br />';
        }
?>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( function() {

if (localStorage.getItem("myKey")) {
    var stored_select = localStorage.getItem("myKey");
    $('#' + stored_select).prop( "selected", true );
    $('.' + stored_select).show();
    } else {
$('.Московская область').show();
}
});

$("#selectItem").change(function(){
    $('.containerss').find('div').hide();
    var selected = $('#selectItem option:selected').attr('id');
    localStorage.setItem("myKey", selected);
    $('.' + selected).show();
});
</script>
</div>
```

И что-то ничего не выходит...
Задача в том, что для выпадающего списка, где каждый город представлен только один раз, выводить всю информацию по нескольким офисам.

Comment: Мне кажется проще всего будет первоначальный массив переформировать с группировкой по городу. Т.е. сделать массив ['id']['город']['офис'].

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис, к сожалению, доступа к первоначальному массиву нет

Comment: вы не пробовали сортировку по ключу записать одной строкой через `return strcmp (...)` ?

Comment: Так я предлагаю пробежаться по тому массиву который вы получаете после json_decode и сформировать другой.

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис Хорошая идея, только как его переформировать-то так...

Answer (score 2):

```
$new_arr = array();
foreach ($addressarray as $key => $office) {
    $new_arr[$office['city_name']][$key] = $office;
}
```

Будет вам массив офисов сгруппированный по городам